# opencv for raw binary files

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have a file that uses opencv to apply a bayer filter to an image to a black and white picture to give it RGB values.  It all works well when I run a 16 bit unsigned integer image through but then when I run a 8 bit unsigned integer I get the following error code:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp, line 276
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:276: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite_
```

Do you know any plugin or extension I can download to deal with more image types?  I am running the program with the Ubuntu command line and the processing program is written in C++.  I did the initial processing to change it from 16bit unsigned integers with the python imaging library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always write the code to convert a 8-bit `unsigned int` image to 16-bit `unsigned int` before running it through. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909464/convert-16-bit-depth-cvmat-to-8-bit-depth) shows you how, piece of cake!

Comment: I didn't actually write the c++ I am just doing the python conversion and don't have a lot of experience with C++ but I think I can figure it out.  would that code just go right in the C++ code?

Comment: this is the code I'm talking about:                            CvMat* depthMetersMat = cvCreateMat( 480, 640, CV_16UC1 );
cv::Mat m2(depthMetersMat, true);
m2.convertTo(m2, CV_8U);  with a few conversions of course for size and switching the types

Comment: I could answer this question if I had access to your code, which I don't. So I guess you're going to have to try and see for yourself.