# OpenCV's cvtColor throws an exception: Invalid number of channels in input image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a `cv::Mat img` which I am trying to convert to `CV_8UC3` using this:

```
cv::cvtColor(img, dst, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
```

It is throwing this error:

```
 Exception: OpenCV(4.2.0) external/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: 
(-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::CvtHelper<cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<1, -1, -1>, 
cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<3, 4, -1>, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<0, 2, 5>, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::NONE>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) 
[VScn = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<1, -1, -1>, VDcn = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<3, 4, -1>, VDepth = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<0, 2, 5>, 
sizePolicy = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::NONE]'
    Invalid number of channels in input image:
    'VScn::contains(scn)' where 'scn' is 3
```

Any ideas what this may mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means image is already "color" (meaning it already has 3 channels). OpenCV can't convert it from `GRAY` to `RGB` because a gray image only has one color channel.

`CV_8UC3` means you have 3 color channels with 8-bit depth. If you really want to make sure you have a `CV_8UC3`, you can try something like this when making your image:

```
// create a new 320x240 image
Mat img(Size(320,240),CV_8UC3);
```

If you share how you are creating `img`, I could confirm this is the case, but at any rate that is what the error means.

## Update

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv) gives some good guidance on debugging your `Mat` objects. According to the error code, you already have a 3 channel image, so that takes care of the `C3` part. The `8U` part means it is all 8 bit unsigned binary data, on a scale of 0 to 255. Once you know the output of the script I mentioned above, you can scale it or convert it accordingly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909464/convert-16-bit-depth-cvmat-to-8-bit-depth) details how to convert to different bit depths.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. The img is created as a result of stitching images together following the opencv detailed stitching algorithm here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp . If I print out `img.type()` it gives me `19` instead of `CV_8UC3` which threw me off. In that case, how can I make sure its type gives me `CV_8UC3` ?

Comment: @alittlebirdy I updated my answer. Try what you see there and tell me what you get.

Comment: Matthew, it looks like my image type is `CV_16S`. According to the second link, I can try something like this: `img.convertTo(img, CV_8U, 0.00390625);` and it works perfectly! Thank you so much!