# Using openCV convertTo to change image bit depth seems to "corrupt" the image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have this `cv::Mat image` of type CV_16SC3 (16 bit signed, 3 channels). Before using `convertTo` to change its depth from 16 bit to 8 bit, the image looks like this:

[image]

I need to make the image this type: CV_8UC3. Tried converting it by:

```
image.convertTo(image, CV_8U, 0.00390625);
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909464/convert-16-bit-depth-cvmat-to-8-bit-depth))

However it resulted in this image here:
[image]

Any ideas why this is and how I can fix it?

Comment: How are you viewing the image after conversion? Are you using `cv2.imshow()` or something else?

Comment: @ZdaR I am saving it using `cv::imwrite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look over OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) at `cv::convertTo` function, the formula used to compute the pixels values is:

```
m(x,y) = staturate_cast<rType>(alpha (*this)(x, y) + beta)
```

This means that the pixel value is multiplied by `alpha` and added with `beta` (= 0 by default).
Your `alpha` value is very low (`alpha = 0.00390625`). This is why you see a black image. Try to use a bigger value for `alpha`. For example, you can use `alpha = 0.7`, or you can use 1, the default value.

Comment: thanks. I assumed from the source that the reason alpha = 0.00390625 was because you have to scale the values from 16 bit to 8 bit or 1/256. WIll give the other alpha values a try.

Comment: Raluca, you are a genius! Works great with alpha = 0.7. Thanks!